# append 3D array using for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to append data in to array like `m[][][]` with the help of for three loop.

```
for i in range (4):
    for j in  range (6):
        for k in range (10):
            m[i][j][k]=i*j*k
print(m)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m = [[[i*j*k for k in range(10)] for j in range(6)] for i in range(4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `m` is not defined when you start your loop python does not know how to access the `[i][j][k]`-th element.

```
m = [] # init the first level
for i in range (4):
    m.append([]) # init m[i]
    for j in  range (6):
        m[i].append([]) #  init m[i][j]
        for k in range (10):
            m[i][j].append( i*j*k ) # add m[i][j] the k-th element
print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your code

```
import numpy
m = numpy.zeros((4,6,10))

for i in range (4):
    for j in  range (6):
        for k in range (10):
            m[i][j][k]=i*j*k
```